# font-face CSS does not appear in HTML

Tags: html, css, font-face, webfonts

I tried many ways and fonts but still not appear to work
**CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'veteran_typewriterregular';
    src: url('veteran_typewriter-webfont-webfont.eot');
    src: url('veteran_typewriter-webfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('veteran_typewriter-webfont-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('veteran_typewriter-webfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('veteran_typewriter-webfont-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('veteran_typewriter-webfont-webfont.svg#veteran_typewriterregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
body{
    font-family:veteran_typewriterregular, sans-sarif;
}
```

I added all font types and urls for all browsers and use it alone in an empty page.Only with html standard tags(,,,).

Comment: go to developer tools and check your sources

Comment: can you show us your file manager? also, can you check if it works if you remove the sans-serif in your body css?

Comment: are the font files in the same folder as your css file?

Comment: This may be related to the *underscore* in the font name

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=McLaren&display=swap');

body{
  font-family: 'McLaren', cursive;
}
```

```html
<a> Hello, my name is Carla</a>
```

If you want to use your solution. First save the font file in a folder in your project.

Comment: It does not work.I tied this too <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script|Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 0):

Where are the font files located? Try to use the absolute url.

```
font-face {
font-family: 'veteran_typewriterregular';
src: url('https://yoursite.com/fonts/veteran_typewriter-webfont-webfont.eot');
```

}

Comment: I have it on my pc, in the same folder too.